# Android Firebase getKey() returning child instead

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database that looks like this:

```
appname:
  chat:
    [ID]:
      child1:value
      child2:value
```

I'm querying it like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = rootReference.child("chat").child([ID]);
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
      long index = Long.parseLong(dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }
  }
```

The problem is, this query doesn't work because `dataSnapshot.getKey()` returns "child1" instead of the ID. It does the same thing for `dataSnapshot.getRef().getKey()`. If I use `dataSnapshot.getRef().getParent().getKey()` I get "chat" back. How do I get back the key for the `DataSnapshot`? I'm extremely confused right now.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot from your Database console showing some data in this format?

Comment: Looks like I screwed up on this question. Turns out the problem was that later in the `ValueEventListener` I was adding another listener and accidentally used `this` instead of `MyClass.this`. Sorry all.

Comment: mind adding a self-answer explaining your mistake and then marking it as accepted so that this question is closed?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was not in the above code. Further into the `ValueEventListener` I made another query and accidentally set the listener to `this` instead of `MyClass.this`. The `ValueEventListener` in `this` was looking for something else, so the query was incompatible.